# Django doesn't find some static files

Tags: html, django

I'm working on a project and since some days, one specific image cannot be found anymore. Everytime I reload the page, this line in the console appears:

```
"GET /staticfiles/my_app/images/Logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 5715
```

I know that the image exists because sometimes it appears for a short moment (until you reload again) and other images in the same folder as the `Logo.svg` are also loading so I guess that the path is not the problem. The setting for the `STATICFILES_DIRS` is also correct since other things do work.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('my_app/static'), )
```

Did anyone have a problem like this before?

Comment: Try setting `STATICFILES_DIRS` like this `STATICFILES_DIRS = 
[ BASE_DIR / 'my_app/static' ]`

Comment: Also did you run python manage.py collectstatic?

Comment: Yes, It didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the main urls.py file make sure that `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` line is included.

Also, if the image is being loaded for a short time it could be a browser cache problem. Try clearing the browser's cache or insert the following on top of HTML template: `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>`